# flutter modal bottom sheet above navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I have an navigation bar with icon button. When i pressed the button i want show modal bottom sheet above the navigation bar(so nav bar was visible). I cant i try long but cant make it.

[image: like this]

I expect to show modal bottom sheet above the navigation bar

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon:Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 54,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)
                ),
              ),
              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    builder: (context) => Container(
                      height:200,
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.share),
                        title: Text('Share'),
                      ),
                    ));
              },
                icon:const Icon(Icons.add_outlined,color: Colors.white,),),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
```

Comment: you can use nested scaffold, it can do the trick

Comment: thaks, i will try

Comment: can you help me please, i donk know how to do like that

Comment: my approach didn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`modal_bottom_sheet`](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) package, just add the parameter `useRootNavigator` and set it to true.

> The useRootNavigator parameter ensures that the root navigator is used to display the bottom sheet when set to true. This is useful in the case that a modal bottom sheet needs to be displayed above all other content but the caller is inside another Navigator.

If you are using Flutter’s internal `showModalBottomSheet`, don’t worry, it also has the same parameter. Just set it to true.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon:Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 54,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)
                ),
              ),
              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    useRootNavigator: true,
                    builder: (context) => Container(
                      height:200,
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.share),
                        title: Text('Share'),
                      ),
                    ));
              },
                icon:const Icon(Icons.add_outlined,color: Colors.white,),),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i tried it doesnt work. I google it but didnt find the answer. I need just add that line right? But id doesnt work

Comment: @Edgar It should work. The trick is to normally place the bottom navigation bar at the bottom of a `Column` instead of using the `bottomNavigationBar` parameter in the `Scaffold` widget.

Comment: Yes with column would work. I must have used column instead of it. But with nav bar it doent work

Answer (score 0):

Since the bottom sheet is executed from the Scaffold, it is necessary to separate the navigation of the NavigationBar (BottomBar) and the bottom sheet. To implement this, it would be beneficial to use the [ShellRoute](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html) from the [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package. For more details, please refer to the link below.

### ShellRoute

```dart
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

```dart
final router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) =>
          BottomNavigationBarScaffold(child: child),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/chat',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const ChatPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/settings',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const SettingsPage(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'terms-of-services',
              parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
              builder: (context, state) => const TermsOfServicesPage(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

- https://medium.com/@ahm4d.bilal/using-gorouters-shellroute-in-flutter-for-nested-navigation-777a9a20642f

### StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack

```dart
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorAKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellA');
final _shellNavigatorBKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellB');
```

```dart
final goRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/a',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    // Stateful nested navigation based on:
    // https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        // the UI shell
        return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation(
            navigationShell: navigationShell);
      },
      branches: [
        // first branch (A)
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorAKey,
          routes: [
            // top route inside branch
            GoRoute(
              path: '/a',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: RootScreen(label: 'A', detailsPath: '/a/details'),
              ),
              routes: [
                // child route
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'details',
                  builder: (context, state) =>
                      const DetailsScreen(label: 'A'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // second branch (B)
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorBKey,
          routes: [
            // top route inside branch
            GoRoute(
              path: '/b',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: RootScreen(label: 'B', detailsPath: '/b/details'),
              ),
              routes: [
                // child route
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'details',
                  builder: (context, state) =>
                      const DetailsScreen(label: 'B'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

- https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar-nested-routes-gorouter/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35663244)